# How can I link ID in ASP.NET MVC5 identity 2.0 default connection with ID in another code first Database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

On my website when someone registers their username, email address and password are stored in the AspNetUsers table in the defaultConnection and they are given an ID. I have created another database so further user details can be stored for the user. How can I link these databases so that when a user registers they have the same id in the defaultConnection and the database which is storing further details for users? 2 databases have to be used

public class ClubMember
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }

```
    public string UserFName { get; set; }

    public string UserLName { get; set; }

    public string UserDescription { get; set; }

    public DateTime UserDoB { get; set; }

}//end User Class
```

These are the further details I want to enter so I would like to match the ID with the default connection ID.